# Has anyone successfully built QuickFIX/J with IntelliJ IDE, importing Maven project structure?

Tags: quickfixj

I ask this question because it sort of builds but not really. 
The core module could not be built; it is missing the `Field` classes.

I do not know how to make the builder generate these classes. I added some dependencies to point to JAR files that were included in folder `\org.quickfixj-2.0.0-bin\org.quickfixj-2.0.0` which came prebuilt. I then no longer get a build problem for module core.

Next, I get errors on anything having to do with a test. I try to build the example `Banzai`. It complains:

> Error:(35, 22) java: package quickfix.field does not exist

for lines like

```
import quickfix.field.AvgPx;
```

---

Environment:

- IntelliJ 2017.2.5
- QuickFixJ  QFJ_RELEASE_2_0_0 2017-11-22